# Access info with 7 digit

Tags: ios, iphone, save

I've got an app idea but there's something I'm not quite sure how to proceed.
I want the user to write some information in textfield then, i want all the info to be saved and a 7 digit numbers to be generated (unique).

Then, if anybody else with the app enter somebody else's number, they get the info saved.

How would you proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution could be done using Parse. You could write the content of the textField into the PFObject, then on the save event on the server side you could create the unique number by simply incrementing. In the completion block for the PFObject you can retrieve the unique digit for sharing.

Comment: But i want the number to be random, not like the first number is 0123456, the second one 0123457 ect..

Comment: Could you use a timestamp or is that not random enough? If it is not random enough, you may be able to use an NSUUID to get a unique across devices string. Though this is now more than 7 digits. At this point you could create a hash or send the hash method to this which reduces you down to your required 7 digits. At this point you need to worry about collisions so you'll need to determine your collision tolerance.

Comment: oh i see, well im looking for between 5 to 6 digit and it can contain letter too (i want it to be kinda of easy to remember)

Comment: So have we effectively answered the question?

Comment: yes, thank you really, first time im using stackoverflow and i'll make sure to use it again, thank you